# C# WPF ComboBox SelectedIndex Change

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ComboBox where the SelectedIndex is set equal to zero.  How do you programatically return the SelectedIndex of a ComboBox when the user selects a new professor and the SelectedIndex changes?  Below is my code so far.

```
System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox comboBox1 = new System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox();
returnedTable = sqlFunctions.getTable("professor");
comboBox1.Items.Insert(0, "Professor");

for (int i = 0; i < returnedTable.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Insert(i + 1, returnedTable.Tables[0].Rows[i]["first_name"].ToString() + " " + returnedTable.Tables[0].Rows[i]["last_name"].ToString());
}

comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;

// Code to capture newly changed selected index??
```

Comment: You may be interested in the MVVM pattern. If you use any other (or no) pattern to work with WPF, you will either come out with a slightly prettier Windows Forms app or you will be fighting WPF all the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SelectionChanged` is the event you're looking for. You can get the `comboBox1.SelectedIndex` value inside this event.

In constructor :

```
public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    comboBox1.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(comboBox1SelectionChanged);
}
```

Now handle the selectionchanged event as below :

```
void comboBox1SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var currentSelectedIndex = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
}
```